# Android webview refused to apply style from stylesheet

Tags: android, webview

webview load url code

```
webviewContent.apply {
                    with(settings) {
                        javaScriptEnabled = true
                        loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                        useWideViewPort = true
                        loadWithOverviewMode = true
                    }
                    webViewClient = tncWebClient
                    val map: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                    map["X-EMP"] = "xlg4R7"
                    map["Content-type"] = "text/javascript"
                    loadUrl(getWebUrl(), map)
                }
```

log cat error

```
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to apply style from 'https://****style.css' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."
```

I was able to load the website but the css style is not applied

Comment: Do yo have access to the server hosting the CSS file? Because your error is saying the browser could not recognise the CSS file type, you need to set the correct ```MIME``` type for the file.

Comment: yes its accessible, is there a config to support specific MIME type?

Comment: This can be set in the ```Content-Type``` header in your server.